# Log4j2 TimeBased Triggering Policy

Tags: java, log4j2

I have touble with the TimeBased Triggering Policy in my RollingFileAppender.

In the [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) it says:

> How often a rollover should occur based on the **most specific time unit**
>   in the date pattern

What is the most specific time unit? Is it the first or the last parameter?
I want the file to rollover once a week.

Here is my code:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/giba.log" filePattern="${baseDir}/giba-%d{w}-%i.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level - %msg%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="7" modulate="true" />
    </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="0">
              <IfFileName glob="*.log" />
              <IfLastModified age="7d" />
            </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile >
```

Comment: It goes on saying "For example, with a date pattern with hours as the most specific item and and increment of 4 rollovers would occur every 4 hours. The default value is 1." - Which does not really specify what they mean by "most specific". I understand it like "Smallest". In the sense of "Minutes are more specific than hours" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most specific time unit means the smallest. Your file pattern uses 'w' so it would roll over weekly. However, you have an interval of 7, which implies you want the file to roll over 7 times during that week.

Frankly, I would like to deprecate the TimeBasedRolloverStrategy. It is confusing and only determines if it should roll as part of writing a log event.  The CronTriggeringPolicy uses a cron expression so doesn't rely on the file pattern at all. It also is driven from a scheduler thread so it will happen whether anything is being logged or not.